# How to change build path for "go build"?

Tags: windows, go, build

I have a project with an _build folder, which contains all the necessary assets for my Go program to run correctly. How  do I automatically move the output of `go build` into that folder?

Comment: `go build -o path/to/your/folder/outfilename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
go build -i -o C:\Users\MyProject\output\
```

it is -o flag

if you have an antivirus -> put this `folder` to antivirus ignoring